# Lua декодировать Base64

Tags: lua, base64

Есть скрипт Lua кодированный, по алгоритму Base64 и компилирован.

Есть функция декодирования: function base64.decode(data)

Как получить исходный код?

Answer (score 1):

о том, «как получить исходный код», на основании предоставленной вами информации, боюсь, ответить невозможно.

а декодировать `file.enc` с помощью функции `base64.decode` можно, например, так:

```
local input_file = io.open( 'file.enc', 'r' )
local output_file = io.open( 'file.dec', 'w' )
output_file:write( base64.decode( input_file:read() ) )
input_file:close()
output_file:close()
```

декодированное содержимое будет записано в `file.dec`.

Comment: а как его декомпилировать?

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы.